# save canvas screenshot into folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have made a screenshot using canvas. Now the screenshot wants to store into a folded. This is what I did.

```
video = document.getElementById('localVideo');
img = document.getElementById('image');

CAPTURE = document.getElementById('Capture');
CAPTURE.onclick = sendDataCAPTURE;
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

function sendDataCAPTURE() {
  canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
  canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
  canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);

  img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1);
  console.log('canvas URL' + canvas.toDataURL('image/webp'))
}
```

Comment: html of CAPTURE?

Comment: i want to save the capture into a specific folder.or change the url into something else so i can save it my self